# Creating array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to create an array to pointers of pNodes but when i declare it i dont know the length of the array

lets see what i mean

this is the Node struct

```
typedef struct _Node {
    struct _Node* next;
    pElement element;
} Node, *pNode;
```

this is the Hash struct

```
typedef struct _Hash {
    int hashSize;
    pNode *hashTable;
}Hash,*pHash;
```

now i want each of the 
hashTable boxes to point to a pNode

the problem is that i dont know the size of the array, if i did it would be like (i guess)

```
pNode hashTable[hashSize]
```

the way i wrote it and tried to resett all boxes to NULL:

this is the CODE:

allocation memory:

```
pHash hash = (pHash)(malloc(sizeof(Hash)));
hash->hashTable = (pNode)(malloc(sizeof(pNode) * size));
hash->hashSize = size;
resetHashTable(hash->hashTable, size); // reseting the array to NULLS
```

the func:

```
static void resetHashTable(pNode *hashTable, int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        hashTable[i] = (pNode)NULL;
    }
}
```

one of the many many errors i get from the program is (the first error)

```
hash.c:37:18: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  hash->hashTable = (pNode)(malloc(sizeof(pNode) * size));
```

can i have some pointers how i need to write it?

Comment: You're casting the result of `malloc` to a `pNode`, and then try to assign it to `hashTable` which is a `pNode*`.

Comment: Do you get a warning about the extra comma in your declarations of pNode and pHash?  (you should)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is not C++ just don't cast `malloc`, you have an error in this line

```
hash->hashTable = (pNode)(malloc(sizeof(pNode) * size));
```

It could be

```
hash->hashTable = (pNode *)(malloc(sizeof(pNode) * size));
                    //   ^ hashTable is declared pNode *
```

A better solution would be

```
hash->hashTable = malloc(sizeof(pNode) * size);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are declared the `pNode` as a pointer.  Then in Hash structure You are declared the `pNode * hastable` So you have to use the double pointer `**`. Or else make that as single pointer in hash structure.

```
 hash->hashTable = (pNode*)(malloc(sizeof(pNode) * size));
```